# Save reading percentage, bookmarks and highlights inside of epub file

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, android, synchronization

Is there  a way or a specific epub reader that can save highlights and bookmarks inside of the epub file.
Basically I would like to have an app that works like kindle on different devices, so that my highlights and bookmarks and reading percentage are synchronized.
I already have a way to synchronize the epub file between different devices, but the reader I tried do not save these information.

I have only Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

*ReadEra*

> Quick access to the reading settings, table of contents, bookmarks, text **highlights**, **quotes**, **notes**, page browsing history in a book and other eBook options. Navigate the book using the page pointer or the progress line. Footnote texts in **Epub**, Mobi, Docx, Fb2 formats are printed at the bottom of the page, as in a paper book. Displays the total number of pages of a book and separately pages of a reading chapter.

If you have books and papers deleted, moved, or downloaded again, ReadEra will automatically find where you left off.